# Unable to write in the ... directory Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload, laravel-5

i have a problem uploading photos in a existing folder.
When i upload a new photo forexample (1).jpg i will split it by whitespace , get the forexample name ,create a folder with that name and upload the picture in that folder.
All fine and dandy but when i upload another photo forexample (2).jpg to go in the forexample folder laravel gives me the error Unable to write in the "....../forexample/" directory.

The code looks like this.It is within a controller.
Thank you peeps in advance.

```
if(Input::file('poze')[0] != null)
{
    //make folder name
    $foldername = explode(' ',Input::file('poze')[0]->getClientOriginalName())[0];

    //make folder path
    $path = substr(storage_path(),0,27).'pozeproduse/';

    if(File::exists($path.$foldername) == false){

        //create folder
        File::makeDirectory($path.$foldername,0777);

        Input::file('poze')[0]->move($path.$foldername.'/',Input::file('poze')[0]->getClientOriginalName());
        $poze = new Poze();
        $poze->poza = substr($path.$foldername.'/'.Input::file('poze')[0]->getClientOriginalName(),26,64);
        $poze->produs_id = $this->request->input('idp');
        $poze->save();


    }else{
        //dd($path.$foldername);
        //foreach(scandir($path.$foldername) as $d){
        //  if($d != Input::file('poze')[0]){

            $obj= new \stdClass();
            $obj->poza = Input::file('poze')[0];

            $obj->poza->move($path.$foldername.'/',Input::file('poze')[0]->getClientOriginalName());
            //dd('break');

            $poze = new Poze();
            $poze->poza = substr($path.$foldername.'/'.Input::file('poze')[0]->getClientOriginalName(),26,64);
            $poze->produs_id = $this->request->input('idp');
            $poze->save();
        //  }
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Then, what's your question dude ? can you please write the error code here ?